# Read text file save each line assign line number and compare

Tags: c#, compare, text-files

I need to compare two text files what I would like to do is read file line by line, assigning for each saved string line number compare and save differences to text file. The biggest problem is some lines such as .0091,.0671,.0105,.872 need to be split and compared invalidly. What would be the easiest way to split them and still store for each separated item same line number.

Example text file lines that contain comma will be split.

```
650,0
'132000/V3'
'17874/V3'
1.5
'30s'
-25,40,35
'CSL'
'EOLC'
.0776
96,13
.0091,.0671,.0105,.872
3625,1215
```

Comment: Your question is currently hard to understand. It would be *much* simpler if you'd give examples, including explaining when lines need to be split and when they don't. It's not really clear where line numbers come in, either...

Comment: Dictionary<int,string[]> ?

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath of Death Dictionary<int,string[]> will produce duplicate keys, line .0091,.0671,.0105,.872 i will have 4 exactly the same keys.

Comment: You mean that when there are commas in a line, you want to split the values like if they were on separate lines ?

Comment: @user3290117 key would be the line. How can same line exist twice?

Comment: Then Tuple<int, int, string[]> to store the index of the value on the line also ?

Comment: @cosmo0 i need to split line convert each to double compare, and if its different log  that there is difference at certain line number.

Comment: ... what ? I'm sorry but I didn't understand a word of this. Please provide an example of the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

An initial approach could be something like this.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFile1.txt");
var fileMap = new Dictionary<int,string[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
     fileMap.Add(i,lines[i].Split(','));
}
```